# Worried this Gypsum Wallboard/Drywall could contain asbestos? Anyone know what this is?

Tags: asbestos

Has anyone dealt with the FIREPROOF Gypsum Wallboard from the National Gypsum Company? Here are the pics: [Wallboard Pics](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNlUDqWbFjyC7k2JmTno3qRQlJR2QlajHzwwkWvu-HmzVr79d5IHhW4ZtatI3lNzA?key=M2ZuelYteGcyUFBxYlZWeDlzeHNidDE3SGxNbmlR)

Comment: Well it could, just quit sniffing the white powder and if you drank from a garden hose according to today's news you are going to die. So what are your concerns . Every house painted prior to the early 70 has lead paint.

Comment: sorry ed, mesothelioma, lung cancer and asbestosis are real diseases.  i don't understand the machismo mental illness that makes it politically correct to downplay the genuine risks these materials present.    not just to the people who choose to work with them (unwittingly or not), but to their families and the families of unknowing customers who get people to do this work for them.    by your logic, we should all smoke, drink, do drugs, whore around and fly stuntplanes maintained by drunken kosovar inbreds.  some of us enjoy life and want to try to stick around for ourselves and our families

Comment: I brought some samples to a lab today for testing.I will know tomorrow afternoon. I spoke with two different experts today and both stated the same thing...its very rare for asbestos to be in the drywall, but they see more cases where it's in the joint compound. fingers crossed, we'll see.

Comment: unfortunately, its not as rare as you might think.  its also a huge function of geography.  many regions never saw it, while many had it in droves.  its also, i am sorry to say, still found in modern compounds from time to time.  and anything from china is always highly suspect.  the closer you are to an eastern or western port city, the more likely that you may have asbestos in your mud currentlly.  the closer you are to the midwest and quebec you are, the more likely you have it historically.  the older it is, the more likely, the newer, the less.  good luck

Comment: Alex did you find out if your “the fireproof gypsum wallboard” contained asbestos or not?

Comment: Hi Julian, it was as expected. The drywall did not have any but the joint compound contained about 2% asbestos. My renovation  work is done and the only thing we did was really wet down the joints before removing the drywall that needed to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Websearch quickly finds http://www.mesothelioma.com/asbestos-exposure/companies/national-gypsum.htm

Determining whether your product is one of those listed as containing asbestos is the challenge. For now I would assume the answer is yes until a test has been done.

Comment: I looked up all the patent numbers that were associated with this board used and nothing came up with asbestos in it. It seems as though all patents must fully explain the materials used in the product. Do you think this a good way of looking at it? I'm only asking seeing as I can't really get any definitive answers tonight. Thanks.

Comment: A list of patents is not a complete ingredients list.

Answer (score 1):

you can just take a sample to the local health testing lab and they can test it for you.  if you cant find one, your local university chem dept should be able to help you directly or to find one.

Answer (score 0):

A chance of asbestos ; as long as it was made before World War 2. PS- I still have an antique college text , from before political correctness. It has a photo of a ( black) African asbestos miner, he is snow white after a day in the mine. Caption says asbestos miners often died before age 50 .

Comment: Interesting remark about the book. I love finding bizarre things like that in old books....although I feel sorry for that miner, for sure. :/